# CSS file not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

So Im using node js with express framework.. the problem is my css file is not found. For other views it just work normally, but when it comes to edit.ejs file it cannot get the css file

I think it related to the url, when I'm pass my the url without ":id" it just work find. It can get the css file. but when I'm using with the ":id" it will not found.

This is the view code (ejs file).
the file name is edit.ejs

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Update Parcel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <label class="logo">ParcelHero</label>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="menu">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="hero3">
      <div class="form-box">
        <div class="fontbox">
          <center>
            <h1>Edit</h1>
          </center>
          <center>
            <h1>Parcel</h1>
          </center>
        </div>

        <form
          action="/update/editPost"
          method="post"
          id="login"
          class="input-group"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            name="tracking_number"
            class="input-field"
            placeholder="Enter new Tracking number"
            required
          />

          <input
            type="text"
            name="owner_name"
            class="input-field"
            placeholder="Enter new parcel owner name"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="owner_phoneNumb"
            class="input-field"
            placeholder="Enter new parcel owner no. phone"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="parcelCourier"
            class="input-field"
            placeholder="Enter new parcel courier name"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="status"
            value="Active"
            class=""
            checked
          />Active
          <input type="radio" name="status" value="Inactive" class="" />
          Inactive

          <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <a href="view">View all parcel</a>
      <a href="search">Search parcel</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the .js file from the server site

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const parcel = require("../models/parcel");
```

app.use("/update", editRouter);

```
//this get request is when I'm click the edit button from view page, and it will display the id at the url. I get the page edit. but did not get the css file.

router.get("/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  parcel
    .findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id, 
      },
    })
    .then((result) => {
      res.render("edit", {
        data: result,
      });
    });
});
```

/output: GET /update/stylesheets/style.css 404 10.334 ms - 1283 */

```
//but when i'm using just this. I will get the css file

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("edit");
});
```

/output:GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.488 ms - - */  //this is the one that work

can someone please help Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `href="stylesheets/style.css"` to `href="/stylesheets/style.css"`.

If you're on the `/update` page, it will prefix `/update` in your href. If you add the `/` in the href, it won't do that.

Adding `/` is like saying "go to the 'root' folder", which means that when the computer/file-manager is looking for files it always starts from the same place. It's all about [file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Comment: Oh wow it works! tq very much. But yeah, I hope someone will explain in more detail about this.

Comment: @alid012, Harrison has added a small explanation and a link to W3schools which also tries to explain this file path behavior